# Questions involving $f(x)=\begin{cases}x+1;&0\le x\le1\\2x^2-6x+6,&1\lt x\le2\end{cases}$ and $g(t)=\int_{t-1}^tf(x)dx$ for $t\in[1,2]$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, continuity, maxima-minima

> Let $f(x)=\begin{cases}x+1;&0\le x\le1\\2x^2-6x+6,&1\lt x\le2\end{cases}$ and $g(t)=\displaystyle\int_{t-1}^tf(x)dx$ for $t\in[1,2]$. Which of the following hold(s) good?
>
> - A) $f(x)$ is continuous and differentiable in $[0,2]$.
> - B) $g'(t)$ vanishes for $t=\frac32$ and $2$
> - C) $g(t)$ is maximum at $t=\frac32$
> - D) $g(t)$ is minimum at $t=1$

A) $f(x)$ is continuous in $[0,2]$ but non-differentiable at $1$.

B) $g'(t)=f(t)-f(t-1)\implies g'(\frac32)=0=g'(2)$

C) $g''(t)=f'(t)-f'(t-1)\implies g''(\frac32)\lt0$

D) $g'(1)\ne0$, but this option is also given as correct.

**Is $g(t)$ really minimum at $t=1$ or could it be a typo?**

Comment: $g''(1)$ does not exist.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, looks like there is a gap in my understanding. For maxima, minima, I would consider $g'(x) =0$ or points where $g(x)$ is non-differentiable. Do we also need to consider the non-differentiability of $g'(x) $?

Comment: In Option c) do you mean $g^{"}(3/2)<0$ ?

Comment: @SubhajitGhosh yes, thanks, edited.

Comment: Maybe this could be the reason for "Is g(t) really minimum at $t=1$?"
$g(t)$ is only defined for $t\in[1,2]$, and f(t-1) is positive in this interval. Therefore $g(\cdot)$ is increasing. Therefore, in the interval $[1,2]$, g(t) is minimum at $t=1$?

Comment: It appears that $g$ does not have a global minimum at $1$ ($g(\frac 3 2)=0$)  but it has a local minimum at  $1$.

Comment: @RahulMadhavan are you focusing on the integration part? If yes, why are we looking at $f(t-1)$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy could you elaborate how you concluded $1$ being the local minimum?

Comment: Compute $g(t)$ for $t>1$ and directly check that $g(t) \geq g(1)$ if $t>1$ and sufficiently close to $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments,$$g(1)=\displaystyle\int_0^1f(x)dx\\=\displaystyle\int_0^1(x+1)dx\\=\left(\frac{x^2}2+x\right)_0^1=\frac32$$

If we calculate $g(t)$ for $t\in(1,2]$, it would be increasingly greater than $\frac32$. Hence, local minimum is at $x=1$.